Migrating from legacy FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) APIs to the HTTP v1 A
After migrating from legacy FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) APIs to the HTTP v1 API, push notifications fails to trigger status bar alerts on the device despite successful token generation and message delivery. What could be the problem?
I tried debugging but not successful. I am expecting a guide from anyone who experienced a similar problem and managed to solve it, or someone who can guide me

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
